# Google sheets match buyers and sellers between sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to match trades between buyers and sellers, with multiple lists on the same file, but on separate sheets with multiple columns, one column for each product.

The first row of each column is the title of the product and underneath there are only either checked or unchecked checkboxes.

The first column contains persons' names and each name will have checked the products they are willing to sell or buy.

So we have the buyers_fresh_produce sheet

```
#     | Beans | Peas |
Mike  |       |  ✓   |
George|   ✓   |      |
```

and the sellers_fresh_produce sheet

```
#     | Beans | Peas |
Mike  |   ✓   |      |
George|       |  ✓   |
```

The expected result would be a matches sheet that allows a user to select his name from a list and then find sellers that sell what he wants to buy and are simultaneously willing to buy what he sells and display them like

```
Mike

Seller  | ProductBuying| ProductSelling |
George  | Peas         | Beans          |
```

Here is a link to a copy of my google sheet, the actual project is for a mobile game where clan mates trade cards, but the logic is the same with the above example. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14dumOTa4sn6hm_pFdZm4cYdtkEFYAlR3lbAfad_dy5w/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: You have jumped to a solution without giving thought to what a successful outcome might look like. Prepare a layout for how you would like to display the matching of buyers and sellers, and then edit your question to include that question. You might also give thought to whether this display is for internal use, or whether it is to be given/accessible by buyers and sellers.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. 
This display will be accessible by buyers and sellers, but the match making sheet will be read-only.
I have included an example of how I would like the matches to be displayed.
The "buyers and sellers" was just an example that is simpler than my actual project, which is about trades in a mobile game, where clan mates can trade cards.
Do you think I should edit this information inside the question?

Comment: "_I have included an example of how I would like the matches to be displayed._" Yes, I saw that but is it realistic? What if there were multiple buyers and sellers for Peas - would that layout be adequate? Or if there were more sellers than buyers or vice versa, who gets the slot(s) without a match? What about a "Matches" sheet, select "Product Type" (various sheet names), and specific product (columns on the respective sheet) from dropdowns, and  list buyers in one column and sellers in another column - but not so as to match a specific buyer and seller as implied by the current layout.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to answer. You are correct about the multiple buyers/sellers. I think it would help us better if it was not product-centered but user-centered, meaning a matches sheet with select your name from a list and then find sellers that have what you want to buy and are simultaneously willing to buy what you sell and display them like SellerName | ProductSelling | ProductBuying. How does that sound to you?

Comment: Possibly (I will need to ponder on that - and test it ;). But I **am** concerned about the repetition of buyer and seller names on the various sheets. I suggest that you need a master list of names (I _was_ thinking of a list of buyers and a list of sellers, but now I appreciate that one person could be a buyer in one market and a seller in another). So a master list of names, and on any given sheet the user name in Column A is selected from a dropdown driven by the master list. (Need to test that also!;)

Comment: That is not a problem, as the actual project is about a specific group of people with specific usernames that will perform the trading.

Comment: Regarding the buyer/seller list. Please create a sample layout showing a successful outcome.

Comment: I hope this helps, you can look at the CommonWants,CommonGives, Trades Found sheets. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14dumOTa4sn6hm_pFdZm4cYdtkEFYAlR3lbAfad_dy5w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: got it. Thanks.

Comment: This is a very complex problem-too broad for stackoverflow. Also, please don't take offence, IMHO you provided no research or ideas for how _you_ would approach the problem. I suggest that _you_ need to document the logic (flowchart/process flow/whatever) for how _you_ would build the "trades_found" sheet. You will then have a scenario that can be built and you can nibble away at each component of the process; you will be able to ask (and hopefully get answers to) bite-sized questions rather than little/no chance of getting useful answers to a very broad question.

Comment: My initial problem was that I could describe what I wanted to do (or so I thought), but I couldn't search for a solution because I didn't know what can and can't be done on google sheets or how I could approach it. You have already provided a big amount of help towards my understanding of the problem and how it could be implemented. I will try to follow your advice. Thank you again for everything!